Does order matter when applying an average and a noise filter?
I am working a temperature sensor. I take reads every 100 miliseconds from and average the last 10 readings per half second. Then I apply a noise filter to that temperature. Note that the noise is generated from the ac filter from the power supply. I can not fix because I am a programmer.
Noise Filter eq.
Where the old_value is the previous filtered temperature.
$$T_{\text{filter}} = \frac{T_{\text{new}} \cdot f + T_{\text{old}}}{1+f},$$
where $0 < f < 1$;
using $f = 0.4$.
My question is, does order matter when applying an average and a noise filter?
Should I be applying the noise filter first to the readings then averaging them?
Am I averaging too much?

"I take reads every 100 miliseconds from and average the last 10 readings per half second." That's a bit hard to understand. 10 readings should cover 1 second , not half a second. Are you down-sampling? Your input is 10 samples per second. Is your output the same rate or different?

Supply noise should be much higher in frequency than temperature sensor noise. Either your claim that the noise is supply noise is wrong, or you need to tell the electrical engineers to, for the sake of even most basic, first-lesson-on-ADCs theory, need an appropriate anti-aliasing filter on the input of their ADC. If they already have one, you need to program your system such that the sampling rate is high enough for that filter.

Anyways, your algorithm seems to be fundamentally wrong. Can you tell me what would happen if your new values (I guess that's the readings from the ADC?) are constant (say, even reading the correct temperature) for say 10, 20 or 100 values in a row?

The problem is my company fire our EEs. I know the ac filters and the power supply are generating noise which the rtds are picking up. The reading are hover around a value but the it spikes between 0.1 to 5 C.

Sampling the rtds at 10hz and averaging the reading is to reduce the noise. And temperature noise filter is the temperature swings because this small reactor has to stable within +/- 0.1 C.
